# script to dump single record from table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to dump single record from mysql table named as table1 for id = 5.

What is mysql query for same?

I think we can use `mysqldump` but i have used it with full records of table. But how to use it with single record?

Comment: You need the .sql file of single record right?

Comment: If the `id` field is your primary key you shouldn't need to limit the result (as Rana did). Perhaps you should read some tutorials on SQL, such as: http://www.itechcollege.com/courses/SQL/02-Select-Data.php

Answer (score 33, accepted):

if you check at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html you will find --where option which is the one you need.

Below follows what is stated in that reference:

```
--where='where_condition', -w 'where_condition'
```

Dump only rows selected by the given WHERE condition. Quotes around the condition are mandatory if it contains spaces or other characters that are special to your command interpreter.

Examples:

```
--where="user='jimf'"
-w"userid>1"
-w"userid<1"
```

Comment: You probably want to specify the table name:
mysqldump -uroot -p databasename tablename -w "id='value'";

Answer (score 4):

I just would like to post a more explicit answer. This is complementary to the accepted one.

```
mysqldump -uremote_user -premote_password -hdatabase_host remote_database_name remote_table_name --where='id=1234' --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info
```

Comment: obiously `--where='id=1234'` should be `--where=id='1234'`

Comment: I have to correct myself. The first equal character can be omitted, but the argument has to be quoted if there are blanks like in  --where 'id IN (193,201,216)'

Answer (score -1):

Although the below will not work for a new/different database

> Try
>
> INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 5);

All one needs to do if inserting across databases on the same server is:

```
INSERT INTO `newdbname`.`table2` (SELECT * FROM `olddbname`.`table1` WHERE id = 5);
```

In fact if I'm not mistaken one can even insert select across databases on different servers in mysql by adding the server name infront of each database name and table as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO `localhost`.`newdbname`.`table2` (SELECT * FROM `accessible-live-server-name`.`olddbname`.`table1` WHERE id = 5);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 5);
```

Comment: this will not work, she want to add record in to different database

Answer (score -4):

Use this query "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id='5' LIMIT 1" . Should work fine.

Comment: I want to get row from one table and insert to another table of another db. So this only would not work

Comment: If the tables are of same structure, then simply use "INSERT INTO table2(the_select_query)" . If you want specific columns, then mention them while selecting and use 'INSERT INTO table2(column1,column2) VALUES(the_specific_slect_query)'